# Upgrading from 2.3.5-p1 to 2.4.3-p1 install issue

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch, composer-update

When I try to run the composer update. I get this error.

- elasticsearch/elasticsearch v7.11.0 requires ext-json >=1.3.7 -> the requested PHP extension json has the wrong version (7.4.24) installed.
  Any idea how to fix it?

I am running PHP 7.4.24 and I have php-json installed.

Answer (score 1):

You cant update from 2.3.5-p1 to 2.4.3-p1 directly.

First you have to upgrade to 2.4.2

Then can change your PHP version to 7.4 and the Composer to 2.x