# After Upgrading from 2.3.5 to 2.4.3-p1 composer.json file is slightly changed, baler is not working

Tags: magento2, baler

[Upgrading from 2.3.5-p1 to 2.4.3-p1 install issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/348619/upgrading-from-2-3-5-p1-to-2-4-3-p1-install-issue)

Yes, I agree with @WebHostigAce
It requires to upgrade to 2.4.2 as it is mentioned here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html

> The following instructions show you how to upgrade Magento using Composer. Magento 2.4.2 introduced support for Composer 2. If you are attempting to upgrade from Magento <2.4.1, you must first upgrade to a version of Magento that is compatible with Composer 2 (for example, 2.4.2) using Composer 1 before upgrading to Composer 2 for Magento >2.4.2 upgrades. In addition, you must be running a supported version of PHP.

I tried below steps to upgrade from 2.3.5 to 2.4.3-p1

I first switched to PHP 7.3 `sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.3` and used composer 1 with PHP 7.3 and then below commands

```
composer require magento/composer-root-update-plugin ~2.0 --no-update
composer update

composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.2 --no-update --force-root-updates
composer update
```

Then I switched PHP version to 7.4 `sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.4;` and downloaded composer.phar file of version 2 https://getcomposer.org/download/ as I didn't want to update composer 1 in my system

Now, below commands with PHP 7.4 and composer 2

```
php -dmemory_limit=5G composer.phar require magento/composer-root-update-plugin ~2.0 --no-update
php -dmemory_limit=5G composer.phar update

php -dmemory_limit=5G composer.phar require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3-p1 --no-update --force-root-updates
php -dmemory_limit=5G composer.phar update
```

It upgrades to 2.4.3-p1 successfully, but I am having doubt when I compared upgraded composer.json file with the file provided by magento as zip archive

I downloaded the zip archive of 2.4.3-p1 from https://magento.com/tech-resources/download

Noticed few things:

composer.json file is not same: the one which I upgraded and the one which they provide in zip format

composer.json file Provided by Magento in zip format

```
"require": {
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.4.3-p1",
    "magento/composer-root-update-plugin": "~1.1",
    "magento/composer-dependency-version-audit-plugin": "~0.1"
}

"require-dev": {
    "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "~1.4",
    "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": "^0.7.0",
    "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.18.1",
    "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
    "magento/magento-coding-standard": "*",
    "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "^3.0",
    "pdepend/pdepend": "~2.7.1",
    "phpcompatibility/php-compatibility": "^9.3",
    "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.8.0",
    "phpstan/phpstan": "^0.12.77",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9",
    "sebastian/phpcpd": "^6.0.3",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~3.5.4",
    "symfony/finder": "^5.2"
},
"conflict": {
    "gene/bluefoot": "*"
}
```

composer.json file after upgrading:

```
"require": {
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.4.3-p1",
    "magento/composer-dependency-version-audit-plugin": "~0.1",
    "composer/composer": "@alpha",
    "magento/composer-root-update-plugin": "~2.0"
}

"require-dev": {
    "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "~1.4",
    "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": "^0.7.0",
    "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.18.1",
    "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
    "magento/magento-coding-standard": "~3.0.0",
    "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "^3.0",
    "pdepend/pdepend": "~2.7.1",
    "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.8.0",
    "phpstan/phpstan": "^0.12.77",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9",
    "sebastian/phpcpd": "^6.0.3",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~3.5.4",
    "symfony/finder": "^5.2"
},
```

1. Missing `phpcompatibility/php-compatibility`, `gene/bluefoot` in upgraded file
2. Version of `magento/composer-root-update-plugin` is 1.1 in original file
3. I can not run upgraded version of Magento 2.4.3-p1 using PHP 7.3
4. The same version of Magento 2.4.3-p1 which I downloaded works with PHP 7.3 where it should not work with PHP 7.3 as per system requirements. It can create confusion, as in devdocs it is mentioned only PHP 7.4 with 2.4.3 in [system requirements](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html)
5. Will the steps I followed create any future issues when upgrading to 2.4.4 for example?
6. Why downloaded version of Magento works with PHP 7.3?
7. I use baler [baler-devtools](https://www.integer-net.com/magento-2-javascript-bundling-baler-devtools/) in version 2.3.5 previously but now Baler doesn't work with upgraded version of magento in 2.4.3-p1 as upgraded magento only works in PHP 7.4 and baler requires < 7.4 (not sure exactly but when I tried to install baler, it shows PHP compatibility error regarding 7.4) And I think Baler will work in downloaded zip format of Magento 2.4.3-p1 as that version of magento works in PHP 7.3 as well (I need to test baler installation with it)

Can anyone clear above doubts I raised and share opinion on the steps I followed please?

Comment: You should not be running 7.3 definitely (EOL). They did remove a lot compared to even 2.4.2 from composer. It was mostly tools that were no longer supported. On production you should not be running and DEV tools anyways - in fact you should be removing them from configuration. Just upgrade the requirements in the Baler plugin manually and have it run from your own repo (bitbucket for example)

Comment: okay I managed to install baler in app/code/Magento mentioned here: https://github.com/magento/m2-baler

@KalvinKlien Can you please share your views on other points I mentioned apart from baler?